# How to go to N-th file as described in the man file for less

Tags: linux, macos, less

I love using `less` to browse files. I often like to move through multiple files.

In the man file it says that one can move N files forward:

```
:n     Examine the next file (from the list of files given in the command line).  If a number N
       is specified, the N-th next file is examined.
```

How do I specify this *number N* to move to the *N-th next file*? I've tried everything but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As described in these answers on the StackExchange network:

> The number must be entered before the command; to skip two files, press `3:n` followed by `Enter`.
> https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676818/377222

Another useful answer https://superuser.com/a/1254274/1056672

> Note: you actually have to type the : for these commands (even though there is a colon visible already).
>
> ```
> :n jump to next file
> :p jump to previous file
> :x jump to first file
>
> 3:n jump 3 files ahead
> 3:p jump 3 files back
> 3:x jump to 3rd file
>
> :f print current file name/info (helpful if you forget where you are)
> ```